# Lapply não retorna o resultado desejado para algumas funções

Tags: r, lapply

Minha lista:

```
structure(list(col1 = structure(list(a = 1:5, b = 1:5, c = 1:5), .Names = c("a", 
"b", "c"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame"), col2 = structure(list(
    a = 6:10, c = 6:10), .Names = c("a", "c"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame"), col3 = structure(list(a = 11:15, 
    c = 11:15), .Names = c("a", "c"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame"), 
    col4 = structure(list(a = 16:20, b = 16:20), .Names = c("a", 
    "b"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame"), col5 = structure(list(
        a = 21:25, c = 21:25), .Names = c("a", "c"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -5L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("col1", "col2", 
"col3", "col4", "col5"))
```

Tentei:

```
res<-lapply(list,function(x)colSums(subset(x,select=c('a'))))
```

e

```
res<-lapply(list,function(x)colMeans(subset(x,select=c(1,2))))
```

e o resultado foi ok.

Mas, quando executo:

```
res<-lapply(list,function(x)shapiro.test(subset(x,select=c(1,2))))
```

não tenho sucesso (`Error: is.numeric(x) is not TRUE`).

O que fazer?

Comment: Esse erro surge simplesmente porque o teste de Shapiro só é aplicável a vetores numéricos, não a data.frames. Da página de help, *"x  a numeric vector of data values."* O teste de normalidade só faz sentido para vetores, cada *vetor* da df pode ou pode não seguir uma distribuição normal. Tal como diz, para os outros casos, `colSums` e `colMeans` está tudo bem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Como muito bem apontado pelo comentário do Rui, a função `shapiro.test` só está definida para vetores. Mas nada nos impede de criarmos uma versão para ela que pode ser aplicada em colunas de data frames:

```
shapiro.test.df <- function(df){
  apply(df, 2, shapiro.test)
}
```

A função `shapiro.test.df` foi criada simplesmente aplicando-se a própria função `shapiro.test` nas colunas de um data frame qualquer. Agora basta usar `lapply` para aplicá-la nos elementos de uma lista, desde que estes elementos sejam data frames:

```
lapply(dados, shapiro.test.df)

$col1
$col1$a

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  newX[, i]
W = 0.98676, p-value = 0.9672


$col1$b

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  newX[, i]
W = 0.98676, p-value = 0.9672


$col1$c

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  newX[, i]
W = 0.98676, p-value = 0.9672



$col2
$col2$a

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  newX[, i]
W = 0.98676, p-value = 0.9672


$col2$c

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  newX[, i]
W = 0.98676, p-value = 0.9672



$col3
$col3$a

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  newX[, i]
W = 0.98676, p-value = 0.9672


$col3$c

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  newX[, i]
W = 0.98676, p-value = 0.9672



$col4
$col4$a

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  newX[, i]
W = 0.98676, p-value = 0.9672


$col4$b

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  newX[, i]
W = 0.98676, p-value = 0.9672



$col5
$col5$a

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  newX[, i]
W = 0.98676, p-value = 0.9672


$col5$c

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  newX[, i]
W = 0.98676, p-value = 0.9672
```